# Issues with Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, relationship

You can take a look at the app I'm referring to at:
http://github.com/585connor/QA

So, I've built this question & answer app... kind of. I can get the
answers to be listed on their respective questions but I cannot figure
out how to get the user info to be displayed on those questions/answers.
For example I'd like to put the username next to each answer and the
username next to each question. Also, when viewing the show action of
the users controller, I'd like to be able to see a list of that
particular user's questions and answers.

There are three tables: questions, answers and users. Can you take a
look at the github repository and try to point me in the right direction
for what steps I should take/concepts I should learn in order to achieve
what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You may want to rename the title of this question. My initial reaction was "This is a programming web site, not a psychology one!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becase you have a

```
belongs_to :user
```

in your question and answer model, you can access the associated user-model by calling .user on a question or answer object:

```
# controller
@question = Question.find :first

# view
<%= @question.user.name %>
```

Accessing the user's questions and answers is similar:

```
# controller
@user = User.find :first

# view
<% @user.questions.each do |question| %>
  <%= question.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, do I paste
    @question = Question.find :first
into the 'show' action so that it replaces the current
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
?

What does the ".find :first" code mean?

Comment: No thats just an example. .find :first gets the first record from the database. You can leave the show action in the controller as it is and access the user with @question.user in the view.

Comment: Hmm, not working. Okay, so I put <%=h @question.user.login %> (this should show the user's username) in the 'show' view for a question and I get an error that says "undefined method 'login' for nil:NilClass". Any idea what could have gone wrong?

Comment: Then the question has no user associated with it. When creating a question you should save which user created it (in the create-method of the questions-controller). Maybe you should also add a validation to the question model that validates the presence of a user.

Comment: Okay, that sounds like it'll be very helpful to me. Could you help me out with what the code what might look like to save which user created a particular question? Would I add this code below the "@question = Question.new(params[:question])" line or is it just a matter of editing that line?

Comment: You should set the user after creation of the object (which is the line with Question.new). It would be the currently logged in user. How you get the currently logged in user depends on which authentication-system you are using and should be documented in its readme.

Comment: Thank you very much, I seem to have gotten it working. Very much appreciated.